# How to logging out web app correctly?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I consider two scenarios:

1. User clicks on "log out" hyperlink, which call "logout.php" (that is easy)
2. User closes tab (window) or closes browser.

And here I do not know, what should I do.
There is a event: `window.onunload` which can be used perhaps like this (not tested):

```
<script>
    var logout_php = function () {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open("GET", "logout.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

    window.onunload = logout_php ;
</script>
```

But when the user opens more tabs and closes just one of them, he will be logged out. Probably it will log out even, when somebody refreshes the same page.

I considered to count all opened tabs with the same domain address, and if there is only one left, then will be the final logout. But this is not possible, because you can not access another windows (tabs) opened in browser.

I am sure, it must be a common problem, but I can not find appropriate answer.

thanx

Comment: Usually web apps just rely on the session expiry for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are used to handle these kind of things. If you logout then your session is destroyed and if someone closes the window directly then in that case their session is destroyed as well. So, as long as you are using sessions, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: I am using sessions, but I thought, I have to destroy them manually. I destroy the session on the logging out, but I am not sure, if the session ID stored on the local computer will be erased imediately after closing all tabs connected to server

Comment: closing the entire window will destroy the session. If there are multiple tabs and only some of them are closed then it doesn't destroys the session automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a keep_live ajax function that calls your server every 1 minute or so updating the last_checkin variable in database or so. If the tab is closed, said function is no longer being called.

In the beginning of every request check if last_checkin is within the last minute (+ some time for connection). If not, redirect to log out (and destroy session if it exists).

This is similar to session timeout. You can have this done every 5 seconds or so. If someone closes his tab and then (for some weird reason) someone else sits on the PC and opens previously closed tabs. Most likely the x time has passed since last check in and user is now logged out.

The down side is the traffic between user and server but it's not a big deal. This is how you check for chat updates anyway so it is done in many services.

Comment: Yes, I was considering this too. I have AJAX request, that constantly fires out to server, so it knows the user is still online. But this is not a "ideal" solution, because as you already said, you can re-enter site within short time interval. If @Kinshuk Lahiri  is right, probably my pain is healed.